# How to set detail & lookup_field in ViewSet in Django rest_framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, router

I want to use two functions in one class.

One function is detail=False, another one is detail=True.

So i want to use two url pattern like these,

```
/userinfo/users
/userinfo/search/(search_key)
```

but i get NoReverseMatch error like below, how can i solve this?

**error**

```
NoReverseMatch at /userinfo/users/
Reverse for 'userinfo-search' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['userinfo/(?P<search_key>[^/.]+)/search/$']
```

**forms.py**

```
class ModelInfoForm(forms.Form):
    search_key = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': 'input keyword',
                'class': 'form-control w-50 mr-sm-2',
                'type': 'search',
                'aria-label': 'search'
            }
        )
    )
```

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'userinfo', UserinfoViewSet, 'userinfo')
```

**view.py**

```
class UserinfoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'user/userinfo.html'

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    lookup_field = 'search_key'

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
    def users(self, request):
        form = ModelInfoForm(request.GET or None)

        serializer = UserSerializer(self.queryset, many=True)
        return Response({'users':serializer.data, 'form':form})

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=True)
    def search(self, request):
            form = ModelInfoForm(request.POST or None)
            search_key = request.POST['search_key']

            for user in self.queryset:
                if not search_key in user.username:
                    self.queryset = self.queryset.exclude(username=user.username)

            serializer = UserSerializer(self.queryset, many=True)
            return Response({'users':serializer.data, 'form':form})
```

Comment: Has this been resolved? I have a similar issue.